# How can we display multiple textarea based on checkbox selection in react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my `react hooks` web app based on check box selection, should be able to display input text area. If the user selected two checkboxes, the right hand side box should display two text area with the checkbox item name. User is allowed to select maximum of 3 checkbox items only.
Now it is displaying only single text area.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import Multiselect from 'multiselect-react-dropdown';

const options = [
    { key: 'Aaron', id: 1},
    { key: 'Bader', id: 2},
    { key: 'Crots', id: 3},
    { key: 'Dan', id: 4},
    { key: 'Elep', id: 5},
    { key: 'Pal', id: 6},
    { key: 'Quilt', id: 7}
  ];

const NominatePerson = () => {

    const maxOptions = 3;
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState([]);

    const handleTypeSelect = (e) => {
        const copy = [...selectedOption];
        copy.push(e);
        setSelectedOption(copy);
    };

    const handleTypeRemove = (e) => {
        const copy = [...selectedOption];
        let index = copy.indexOf(e);
        copy.splice(index, 1);
        setSelectedOption(copy);
    };

    const onNominate = () => {
        alert("hello")
        // ...
    };

  
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="navbar-nav">
                <div className="leftNavItem">
                    <a><Link to={'/dashboard'} className="nav-link"> <b>Dashboard</b> </Link></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h1>Nominate a person</h1>
            <div className="nomineeSelectBox">
                <Multiselect
                    onSelect={handleTypeSelect}
                    onRemove={handleTypeRemove}
                    options={selectedOption.length + 1 === maxOptions ? [] : options}
                    displayValue="key"
                    showCheckbox={true}
                    emptyRecordMsg={"Maximum nominees selected !"}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="nomineesSelectedList">
                {selectedOption.length ? (
                    <input type="textarea" className="nomineechoosed"></input>
                ) : (<div></div>)
                }
            </div>
            <div className="nominateButton">
                <input type="button" value="Next" onClick={onNominate}/>
            </div>
            
            
        </div>

        
    )
}

export default NominatePerson
```

`screenshot`
[image]

Comment: Your question is very general. Could you be more specific about what you've already tried or what part you are struggling with?

Comment: Please refer my screen shot, I have selected two checkbox items, for the selected item I should display two text area on right hand side.

Comment: But now it is displaying only a single text area.

Comment: Need to display selected item name and text area on right hand side. If I have selected 3 items, 3 text area with respective name on top of text area should display on right side

Comment: I believe I have problem in this part
 {selectedOption.length ? (
                    <input type="textarea" className="nomineechoosed"></input>
                ) : (<div></div>)
                }``

Comment: You can use `map` to produce a list of nodes from an array. See: [https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div className='nomineesSelectedList'>
  {selectedOption.map((x, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i}>
          <p>{x[i].key}</p> 
          <input type='textarea' className='nomineechoosed' />
      </div>
     )))}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, how can i pass selected item name above of each text area ?

Comment: Thank you, please see my option in my question  : ``const options = [
    { key: 'Aaron', id: 1},
    { key: 'Bader', id: 2},
    { key: 'Crots', id: 3},
    { key: 'Dan', id: 4},
    { key: 'Elep', id: 5},
    { key: 'Pal', id: 6},
    { key: 'Quilt', id: 7}
  ];`` If I pass {x.key} will get the selected item name ?

Comment: @soccerway I think so. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I have tried `<p>{x.key}</p>`. but not getting the selected item

Comment: @soccerway Try ```console.log(x)``` just before ```return``` and tell me what is the output

Comment: I have added the screenshot for reference while iterating.

Comment: Just added `<p>{x[i].key}</p>` fixed the issue. Thank you